# Django is becoming synchronous on importing channels

Tags: sockets, http2, django-channels, asgi, django-channels-presence

On including the channels in my project (installed_apps), it has become synchronous. I'm using django 3.2.4. if I remove those channels and try, my django server is able to process multiple requests asynchronously(when I'm hitting from postman). Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

See the discussion here https://github.com/django/channels/issues/1587. Basically you must run WSGI+ASGI separately according Django's team.

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better. Also, provide a basic coverage of the content of your link, in case it stops working in the future.